# How do I threshold to zero using adaptive thresholding in opencv?

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to use `cv2.adaptiveThreshold()` but for my purposes, it would be ideal if I could threshold to zero rather than to binary. I tried using the flag `cv2.THRESH_TOZERO` like you can with `cv2.threshold()` but it threw an error. How could I do this, and if I can't do it with `adaptiveThreshold()`, how can I do it otherwise? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. Thanks anyways for your help @Masoud!
I used this code:

```
    imgb = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(img, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, \ 
    cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 255, -9)
    img[np.where(imgb == 0)] = 0
```

I used numpy to find where the binary image was equal to zero, and I set the original grayscale image to zero in those locations.

Answer (score 1):

From opencv [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html?highlight=adaptivethreshold), `cv2.adaptiveThreshold` has only two thresholding types:

> Thresholding type that must be either THRESH_BINARY or THRESH_BINARY_INV .

So for adaptive shareholding, if similar behavior of `cv2.THRESH_TOZERO` is desired, its possible to multiply original image and binary image resulted from thresholding. For example:

```
thresh_binary = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(img, 1, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 11, 220)
thresh_tozero = cv2.multiply(img, thresh_binary)
```

Comment: This didn't work for me. When I did this, it looked like the original binary image but with some odd gray smudges.

Comment: @tr2002a. I edited the code. changed the `maxValue` to 1.